# Loggin in via post request from chrome extension popup

Tags: jquery, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make requests from my google chrome extension to my web server (python/django). Problem is when I do a post request to the server to log the user in, the session cookies aren't being saved anywhere, so the user doesn't get logged in.

```
$('#login-btn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("body").addClass("loading");

        $.post('http://pennypledge.co/manager/', {
                email: $('#emailfield').val(),
                password: $('#passwordfield').val(),
                a: 'login'
        },
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
               $("body").removeClass("loading");
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
```

Has anyone run into this problem before? Do I have to set the cookies manually? If so, how do I read the cookies from the response of a jquery post?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome.cookies API (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) that you can use to interact with cookies.